# First "git push" to remote repository. Can't find where it places the files of the project

Tags: git, github

I'm new to git and for the last couple of hours I 've been trying to setup a remote repository of a local project.

So I followed the instructions:

```
# on the remote server
cd path/to/myapp.git
git --bare init
```

then:

```
# on local machine
git remote add <name> root@<ip>:path/to/myapp.git
git push <name> master
```

It successfully pushes the project:

`Writing objects: 100% (729/729), 14.68 MiB | 56 KiB/s, done.`

However I can't find where it places the project files. I have looked everywhere: path/to/myapp.git subfolders, parent folders, even used the *find* command to search the whole disk.

What am I doing wrong?

---

UPDATE: So basically I took the wrong path. On remote machine I should

```
git clone <local_repository_url>
```

to get an exact copy of the local project

and then on the local machine

```
git push <name>
```

to push changes.

Comment: Please don't update your question to include the answer. Either post it as an answer and accept it, or add a comment to the answer which helped you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing everything perfectly fine (presumably). A bare repository is one without any working copy, so all content is stored in a git-internal way. Look at /path/to/myapp.git/objects/. In this folder there are lots of files, that correspond to Git objects.

To see, what any of these objects really contains, you can use

```
git show <OBJECT-ID>
```

For details I recommend [this chapter in the Git Book](http://book.git-scm.com/1_the_git_object_model.html).

Answer (score 1):

GIT is storing changesets in its object-data-base (compressed). You cannot find your files simply like that with find.

See the objects/-folder in the .git-folder or in the bare-repository.

Comment: Actually git doesn't store "changesets". Git commits are not delta-based.

Answer (score 1):

A bare repo won't display any file, since it won't checkout said file in a working tree.

See "[What is a bare repo](http://sitaramc.github.com/concepts/bare.html)":

> A "bare" repo, as the git glossary says, is a repository that does not contain a "working tree" at all.
>   It doesn't contain the special `.git` sub-directory either; instead, it contains all the contents of the `.git` subdirectory right in the main directory itself.